# handle tap gesture with an argument iphone / ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

when my tap gesture fires I need to send an additional argument along with it but I must be doing something really silly, what am I doing wrong here:

Here is my gesture being created and added:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:itemSKU:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Here is where I handle it:

```
-(void) handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender withSKU: (NSString *) aSKU {
        NSLog(@"SKU%@\n", aSKU);
}
```

and this won't run because of the UITapGestureRecognizer init line.

I need to know something identifiable about what image was clicked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A gesture recognizer will only pass one argument into an action selector: itself. I assume you're trying to distinguish between taps on various image subviews of a main view? In that case, your best bet is to call `-locationInView:`, passing the superview, and then calling `-hitTest:withEvent:` on that view with the resulting `CGPoint`. In other words, something like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
...
- (void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIView *theSuperview = self.view; // whatever view contains your image views
    CGPoint touchPointInSuperview = [sender locationInView:theSuperview];
    UIView *touchedView = [theSuperview hitTest:touchPointInSuperview withEvent:nil];
    if([touchedView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        // hooray, it's one of your image views! do something with it.
    }
}
```

Comment: at least I can stop banging my head on passing more than 1 argument - thanks!    
But I am still left in the same spot, trying to figure out something to identify which image was clicked.  I know an image was clicked already because it's the only thing in that view responding to the tap, just don't know which one.

Comment: sorry clicked = tapped in the above

Comment: is there a way to get an index of where the view is in the superview?  Say I added 40 UIImageViews and the send was 28 - that would work perfectly for me.

Comment: In the code I provided above, touchedView get set to the image view that was tapped. You might set each view's "tag" property to a distinct number when you create it, then retrieve the tag in the above method and index that against your array of SKUs.

Comment: DOH - sweet!  I saw that I could set a tag to an int, just didn't click in my head - thanks!

Comment: You can add a tag to a imageView. And that tag can be the order inside a array for instance.