# How to implement multiple simultaneous custom gestures in IOS?

Tags: ios, ios5

Hi! My problem is not how to implement multiple custom gesture but how to handle multiple Custom Gestures. I have added a pinch custom gesture on corner points of the view and one finger rotation gesture on the view. For pinch custom gesture on corner points, I've used `SPUserResizableView` and for one finger custom gesture, I've used `KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer`. But only one gesture is working. How can I resolve this? I've even tried using `SPUserResizableView` and default rotation gesture and it's not working. What may be the issue? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

may this links can help you.    [Simultaneous gesture recognizers in Iphone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627934/simultaneous-gesture-recognizers-in-iphone-sdk)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160489/handle-tap-gesture-with-an-argument-iphone-ipad
```

Check it out it's all about gestures ,you doesn't need to use KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer and SPUserResizableView.

Comment: Thank You.But what i need is to have only gestures for the corner points of the image only.Thats why i need to use KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer and SPUserResizableView.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use SPUserResizableView to handle the pinch gesture in the corners. You could probably get away with transparent subviews created programmatically, with the pinch gesture recognizer added to them.

Comment: Sorry.I can't get you clearly.So could you please give me an example of your previous statement so that it will make me understand better.